# Constructing Asp.Net IEnumerable ViewModels with eager loading and custom business logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Model:

```
public class Company
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class JobListing
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public Company Company {get;set;}

  public bool JobListingHasRecommendation {get;set;}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class JobListingVM
{
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public string CompanyName {get;set;}

   public string TitleAtCompany 
   {
      get
      {
         return string.Format("{0} at {1}", Title, CompanyName);
      }
   }

}
```

Repository method:

```
public IEnumerable<JobListing> getAllJobs()
{
   return dbContext.JobListings;
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var jobs = repository.getAllJobs();//jobs is now disconnected from the dbcontext

   //let's say there are a thousands of jobs (and we will be paging)

   //now we use some Automap like magic to convert the IEnumerable<JobListing> into        
   //IEnumerable<JobListingVM>


}
```

The problem is getAllJobs has to either eager load the Company property
and the Automap process relies on this knowledge
or Automap runs N queries for N jobs to get the Company - and this is clearly bad practice

While the solution to this maybe is to eager load the Company property in the 
repository then what happens to cases where one doesn't want the eager load.
We need many combinatorial repository methods to provide all eager/lazy load (with 
potentially nested eager load etc) scenarios?

JobListingHasRecommendation property of the VieModel is also a problem because it requires custom business logic involving db queries to set it, so this needs to be done per JobListing for all the members of the IEnumerable.  Doing this inside the controller after the repository call is messy and doing it inside the automapping requires an IRepository injected in to the Automapping construct.

The mapping of Models to ViewModels is not as straightforward as all the automapping examples I see.  I rarely see an example where a list of Models are mapped to a list of ViewModels and each ViewModel's JobListingHasRecommendation must be calculated individually.  There are performance and architecture issues here as the automapping service now has to also have database access...

My question is - since ViewModels store data that can be the result of complex calculations and sequential set of database accesses, what is the best practice to create an IEnumerable of these types of ViewModels.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a repository dedicated only for querying with a light model? Basically, the repository will return directly the view model (or parts of it). The repository will be responsable to query the orm and to get only the columns needed. Your current repository method doesn't do anything, make it to select only the needed data which then will be mapped to the view model directly.

Comment: MikeSW - how would you determine the returned class contracts for many different sub selects (or includes) of the same entity?  You could have select and include be method params (using dynamic linq for the select and the EF string include functionality for the include param), but what would the return type be for such a flexible select repo method?

Answer (score 0):

Specify what you want to eager load via Include(), and return ToList()

```
return dbContext.JobListings.Include(o=>o.Customers).ToList(); //or whatever you want to eager load
```